# Building digital transactions for google assistant applications

Tags: actions-on-google

I wanted to clarify something about the way in action transactions are working for google home.

From my understanding, I must create an app on the google play store, this will have its own SKU, which I can then utilise with the google api to process a transaction.

However, this app for the play store will have no functionality beyond being a key to unlock more features in my google action.

Is there any other way for me to get an SKU without creating an 'empty' play store app?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no other way. The Assistant is using the Play Store infrastructure to manage digital resources, and the Play Store requires an app.

I've been told (but have not yet tested) that this "app" really needs to be nothing more than a manifest that includes the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING">
```

(And, I assume, is bundled into a signed APK.)